# What version of Eclipse is included with the SDK ADT bundle for Android Dev?

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, development-environment

See http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
I want to know whether the bundle contains the buggy version of Eclipse (I think Juno) as well as just for curiosity's sake whether they use classic or java or java ee.

Comment: Definitly a good question +1

Comment: Elipse about does not show the version OR the flavor, why is this a off topic question ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

4.2.

Look into the eclipse/readme/readme_eclipse.html file in the adt folder and you'll find versioning information.

Answer (score 4):

If you are particular about which version of Eclipse you want, simply download your favorite version and the "SDK Tools Only" bundle then follow the "Existing IDE" directions.

It looks like the IDE bundle contains Juno (3.8) for Mobile Development, but I'm not 100% on that. I am unaware if this is the "buggy" version or if that's 4.x.